# Stanford NLP - NER & Models

Tags: stanford-nlp

I was looking at the online demo: http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/ner/process
Try a simple testcase like: *John Chambers studied in London (UK) and Mumbai (India).*
The 3-class Classifier identifies the Person, the 7-class Classifier does not identify the Person. Seems like I need to run the parser on both the Models: once to identify Person, Location & Organization. And once just for Currency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run this command it finds all of the appropriate entities on your example:

```
java -Xmx8g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner -file sample-sentence.txt -outputFormat text
```

When you run the NERCombinerAnnotator which corresponds to the annotator `ner` it will run a combination of several models automatically for you.

Comment: Info on the ner annotator: http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/ner.html

Comment: Thanks! The currency parser works great for $ entities. How do I get it to work for Indian Rupee, for example: BSES has invested over Rs 7200 crores on upgrading and augmenting the infrastructure.